# Notice : Trying to get property of non-object in php

Tags: php

I'm working on some API call where I got following response from the server.

```
object(stdClass)#3 (7) { 
    ["0"]=> object(stdClass)#4 (6) { 
        ["id"]=> string(1) "1" 
        ["name"]=> string(9) "test list" 
        ["cdate"]=> string(19) "2014-12-07 17:36:29" 
        ["private"]=> string(1) "0" 
        ["userid"]=> string(1) "1" 
        ["subscriber_count"]=> int(3) 
    } 
    ["1"]=> object(stdClass)#5 (6) { 
        ["id"]=> string(1) "2" 
        ["name"]=> string(6) "List 3" 
        ["cdate"]=> string(19) "2014-12-07 18:12:49" 
        ["private"]=> string(1) "0" 
        ["userid"]=> string(1) "1" 
        ["subscriber_count"]=> int(1) 
    } 
    ["result_code"]=> int(1) 
    ["result_message"]=> string(30) "Success: Something is returned" 
    ["result_output"]=> string(4) "json" 
    ["http_code"]=> int(200) 
    ["success"]=> int(1) 
}
```

Now, I'm looking to get only "name" from above result using below function:

```
foreach ($response as $key => $object) {
     echo $object->name;
}
```

This function works fine but return with error :

```
"Trying to get property of non-object in...."
```

What I'am doing wrong here? What is the correct way to handle this stdClass ?

Comment: There is no array in your code.

Comment: can you do a var_dump to see what it returns?

Comment: I have pasted var_dump only.

Comment: You have no array in your code. There is no foreach when there is no array.

Comment: Ok! but then How should I get "name" for each stdClass ?

Comment: This is a strange way to return the details, normally you'd have a class variable that contains an array of the lists. Then you could iterate through them with a `foreach`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange object you have, just check if the key is numeric:

```
foreach( $response as $key => $object ) {
    if ( is_numeric( $key ) ) echo $object->name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no array in the code posted in your question. `stdClass` does not implement `\Traversable` so the best you can get is php trying to fix your error for you resulting in an error or unwanted behaviour.

Anyway as your result is supposedly generated by json input you might want to specify the second parameter of `json_decode` which will return an array instead of a `stdClass`, which allows you to iterate using foreach.

If you still want to (or need to) work with the `stdClass`-based result you can use the following syntax to access any property, even if it wouldn't be valid to declare it in this form.:

`var_dump($response->{"0"}->name);`

Answer (score -2):

try this code

```
foreach ($response as $key => $object) {
     echo (string)$object->name;
}
```

Comment: I tried that too.. but then I get Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array